# Tricks to remember syntax in android

Tags: android

I am new in android and I have a big problem with remembering syntax. Anyone have some tricks to remember it then give me please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to the XML tags/attributes or the Java syntax? Using Eclipse's auto-suggest should be helpful in both cases.

Comment: java syntax.example of that if i need to make a gallery in android app then how to remember its all classes and methods?

Comment: The best trick I know is to keep certain pages bookmarked such as SO and the Android docs and look up the syntax you need when you forget it. It will take about 3 seconds. The more you program the easier it will be to start remembering. I have been doing Android dev for over a year and still have to look up the syntax of some commands. There are too many to remember everything...that's why its all in the docs. This is really too broad to answer and is not a specific programming question.

Comment: ctrl + space helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In either XML or Java, you will get auto-complete when you start typing API calls or, defining attributes in layout files.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> will provide API or Attribute auto-complete options.

Also, try <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (mac) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (Windows) for quick text options.